# Disable highlight on tableview

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

How to disable highlight on tableview without disable the func? i tried these and now i can't go to the another page.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the selectionStyle property of your UITableViewCell to `.None`.
This will permit selection but prevent the default highlighting behavior.

Answer (score 2):

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation in your controller, set the `selectionStyle` to `.None` as below:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.selectionStyle = .None

    // ...

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Step 1: Select your Tableview Cell

[image]

> Step 2: After then go to Tableview Cell Properties and Set your
>   Tableview Cell Selection **".None"**

[image]

> - Or you can also Do Programmatically add **"Tablecell.selectionStyle = .none
>     "** this code in your *cellForRowAtIndexPath* method.

Comment: I think You select your Tableview you need to select your Cell then Click on Selection and you'll get None -  Robert Dresler

Comment: you can add Programmatically or Storyboard through ?? - Robert Dresler

Comment: In Swift this enum case is named `none`

Comment: I have changed my Answer, thanks for finding my mistakes - Robert

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191393/discussion-between-dhaval-gevariya-and-robert-dresler).

Answer (score 0):

I believe disabling selection should do the trick.

```
tableView.allowsSelection = false
```

Or, if you want the user to be able to temporarily tap the table you could do this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //your code
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
}
```